# Assigning argument to a positional parameter

Tags: bash, positional-parameter

I am calling a shell script that has a large number of arguments e.g. `./train-rnn.sh 0 0 0 "63 512"`. Is it possible to assign each argument to a specific positional parameter ? e.g.

`./train-rnn.sh $1=0 $2=0 $4=0 $3="63 512"`

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: Not in anything like this form. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Bash has no mechanism for that, but you can cook something up.

The best way would be to parse the command line arguments inside your script. In that case, you might want to improve your user experience by allowing options of the form `option=argument` instead of having the user (and developer too!) remember the meaning of `$1`, `$2`, and so on.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
declare -A opt
for arg; do
  if [[ "$arg" =~ ^([^=]+)=(.*) ]]; then
    opt["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"]=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  else
    echo "Error: Arguments must be of the form option=..." >&2
    exit 1
  fi
done
# "${opt["abc"]}" is the value of option abc=...
# "${opt[@]}" is an unordered (!) list of all values
# "${!opt[@]}" is an unordered (!) list of all options
```

Example usage:

```
script.sh abc=... xyz=...
```

If you really want to stick to the positional parameters, use

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
param=()
for arg; do
  if [[ "$arg" =~ ^\$([1-9][0-9]*)=(.*) ]]; then
    param[BASH_REMATCH[1]]=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  else
    echo "Error: Arguments must be of the form $N=... with N>=1" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
done
if ! [[ "${#param[@]}" = 0 || " ${!param[*]}" == *" ${#param[@]}" ]]; then
  echo "Error: To use $N+1 you have to set $N too" >&2
  exit 1
fi
set -- "${param[@]}"
# rest of the script
# "$@" / $1,$2,... are now set accordingly
```

Example usage:

```
script.sh $1=... $3=... $2=...
```

Above approach can also be used as a wrapper in case your script/program cannot be modified. To do so, replace `set -- "${param[@]}"` by `exec program "${param[@]}"` and then use `wrapper.sh $1=... $3=... $2=...`.

Comment: Regexes need the `=~` operator and `opt[BASH_REMATCH[1]]` should be `opt[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]`.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Thank you for the notice. I corrected the typo `=`/`=~` and the error `opt[BASH_REMATCH[1]]`. I'm so used to having regular arrays whose `[...]` are an arithmetic context that I totally forgot the `$` here.